# Saving Grid Data using PHP in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, grid, save

I have used an array but it's not working.

The code is as below:

```
$resource = $_POST['resource'];
    for ($i=0; $i<count($resource); $i++) 
    {

        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_user_permissions (`resource`,`role_id`,`membership_id`,`create`,`read`,`update`,`delete`,`approve`) VALUES ('".$_POST['resource'][$i]."','".$_POST['role_id']."','".$_POST['membership_id']."','".$_POST['create'][$i]."','".$_POST['read'][$i]."','".$_POST['update'][$i]."','".$_POST['delete'][$i]."','".$_POST['approve'][$i]."')");


    }
```

When doing a `print_r($_POST'resource']`, it gives me following output:

```
User [4] => Groups [5] => Sub Groups [6] => Roles [7] => My Trucks [8]
=> My Drivers [9] => e-Confirm [10] => e-Trak [11] => Product & Pricing [12] => Content Management ) 1Array ( [0] => Post Load [1] => Load Truck [2] => Truck Post [3] => User [4] => Groups [5] => Sub Groups [6] => Roles [7] => My Trucks [8] => My Drivers [9] => e-Confirm [10] => e-Trak [11] => Product & Pricing [12] => Content Management ) 1Array ( [0] => Post Load [1] => Load Truck [2] => Truck Post [3] => User [4] => Groups [5] => Sub Groups [6] => Roles [7] => My Trucks [8] => My Drivers [9] => e-Confirm [10] => e-Trak [11] => Product & Pricing [12] => Content Management ) 1Array ( [0] => Post Load [1] => Load Truck [2] => Truck Post [3] => User [4] => Groups [5]
=> Sub Groups [6] => Roles [7] => My Trucks [8] => My Drivers [9] => e-Confirm [10] => e-Trak [11] => Product & Pricing [12] => Content Management ) 1Array ( [0] => Post Load [1] => Load Truck [2] => Truck Post [3] => User [4] => Groups [5] => Sub Groups [6] => Roles [7] => My Trucks [8] => My Drivers [9] => e-Confirm [10] => e-Trak [11] => Product & Pricing [12] => Content Management ) 1Array ( [0] => Post Load [1] => Load Truck [2] => Truck Post [3] => User [4] => Groups [5]
=> Sub Groups [6] => Roles [7] => My Trucks [8] => My Drivers [9] => e-Confirm [10] => e-Trak [11] => Product & Pricing [12] => Content Management ) 1Array ( [0] => Post Load [1] => Load Truck [2] => Truck Post [3] => User [4] => Groups [5] => Sub Groups [6] => Roles [7] => My Trucks [8] => My Drivers [9] => e-Confirm [10] => e-Trak [11] => Product & Pricing [12] => Content Management ) 1Array ( [0] => Post Load [1] => Load Truck [2] => Truck Post [3] => User [4] => Groups [5]
=> Sub Groups [6] => Roles [7] => My Trucks [8] => My Drivers [9] => e-Confirm [10] => e-Trak [11] => Product & Pricing [12] => Content Management ) 1Array ( [0] => Post Load [1] => Load Truck [2] => Truck Post [3] => User [4] => Groups [5] => Sub Groups [6] => Roles [7] => My Trucks [8] => My Drivers [9] => e-Confirm [10] => e-Trak [11] => Product & Pricing [12] => Content Management ) 1Array ( [0] => Post Load [1] => Load Truck [2] => Truck Post [3] => User [4] => Groups [5]
=> Sub Groups [6] => Roles [7] => My Trucks [8] => My Drivers [9] => e-Confirm [10] => e-Trak [11] => Product & Pricing [12] => Content Management ) 1Array ( [0] => Post Load [1] => Load Truck [2] => Truck Post [3] => User [4] => Groups [5] => Sub Groups [6] => Roles [7] => My Trucks [8] => My Drivers [9] => e-Confirm [10] => e-Trak [11] => Product & Pricing [12] => Content Management ) 1Array ( [0] => Post Load [1] => Load Truck [2] => Truck Post [3] => User [4] => Groups [5]
=> Sub Groups [6] => Roles [7] => My Trucks [8] => My Drivers [9] => e-Confirm [10] => e-Trak [11] => Product & Pricing [12] => Content Management ) 1Array ( [0] => Post Load [1] => Load Truck [2] => Truck Post [3] => User [4] => Groups [5] => Sub Groups [6] => Roles [7] => My Trucks [8] => My Drivers [9] => e-Confirm [10] => e-Trak [11] => Product & Pricing [12] => Content Management ) 1
```

Comment: $_POST['resource'] is array?

Comment: `print_r($_POST['resource'])` and paste the output of it into your question

Comment: $_POST['resource'] is array which i am printing dynamically

Comment: pls find the image here so than you can get it more clear http://freight.lunchbite.com.au/images/roles.png

Comment: pls find the image on link http://freight.lunchbite.com.au/images/role1.png.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* First i make the variable $i is 13 because i see there 13 record */

for ($i=0; $i<14; $i++){
    $resource = !empty($_POST['resource'][$i]) ? $_POST['resource'][$i] : 0;
    $create = !empty($_POST['create'][$i]) ? $_POST['create'][$i] : 0;
    $read = !empty($_POST['read'][$i]) ? $_POST['read'][$i] : 0;
    $update = !empty($_POST['update'][$i]) ? $_POST['update'][$i] : 0;
    $delete = !empty($_POST['delete'][$i]) ? $_POST['delete'][$i] : 0;
    $approve = !empty($_POST['approve'][$i]) ? $_POST['approve'][$i] : 0;
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 
        tbl_user_permissions 
        (`resource`,`role_id`,`membership_id`,`create`,`read`,`update`,`delete`,`approve`) 
        VALUES 
        ('".$resource."','".$_POST['role_id']."','".$_POST['membership_id']."',
        '".$create."','".$read."','".$update."',
        '".$delete."','".$approve."')");
}
```

Comment: but when i check only last rows checkboxes then values are going into first rows

Comment: check your form submit are that true **name** and **value**

Comment: pls check the screenshot in which first rows values should have inserted in last rows since i have checked last rows checkboxes.                                       http://freight.lunchbite.com.au/images/db.png                                                 should i use multidimentional array?

Comment: i tried @Alghi Fari but the same thing is happening. :(